# How to tail a log file with timestamps and count occurrences in the last X seconds

Tags: python

I have a log files that I read/stream into Python (it contains timestamp and data) using tail.

I need a way to see if, in the last 10 seconds, how many lines were seen/observed based on a filter (e.g. line contains "error")

I'll be checking every X seconds to see how many lines were present for "error" or "debug" etc... The count should only look at the last X seconds.

Example:

A log file which Python tails is

```
2022-11-15 14:00:00,000 : Error 1923
2022-11-15 14:00:01,000 : Error 1456
2022-11-15 14:00:01,400 : Error 1001
2022-11-15 14:00:03,400 : Error 1124
2022-11-15 14:00:05,400 : Normal 0011
2022-11-15 14:00:06,400 : Error 1123
```

When I read the file, in Python; I want to answer the question

*In the last X seconds, how many times have I seen Error or How many times have I seen Normal?*

How would I accomplish this whilst I tail a file to check the last 10 seconds or 20 seconds etc.?

Comment: Is your problem how you can count stuff, or how you can get all lines which have timestamps that are within the last X seconds?

Comment: Timestamp isnt important, just within the last X seconds. I am happy to "restamp" them as they come in

Comment: Do you not need the timestamp to determine if a line is from the last x seconds?

Comment: Timestamp can be from either the file OR during the file being read real time.

Comment: You can use the python function groupby and group the lines according to any criteria you specify https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite simple solution that looks at the current timestamp (I hardcoded the timestamp to follow the timestamps from your example but you can use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead).

Simply put, the following was done:

- I made a file called `test.log` with the exact contents of that python tails piece of text you made above, which I read in using Python
- Then you should be able to simply run and tweak the following code:

```
import datetime
import re

with open('test.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Defining the interesting interval of time
seconds_interval = 4
interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds_interval)
# You could use now = datetime.datetime.now() but this is for this test
now = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 15, hour=14, minute=00, second=6)

# This is the function that grabs the interesting lines, and is used in the
# filter operator
def grab_interesting_lines(line):
    strDate = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line).group(0)
    date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return date_time_obj >= now - interval

# Now we're actually filtering. The interesting_lines object is an iterator over
# which we can loop later on
interesting_lines = filter(grab_interesting_lines, lines)

# Now we simply loop over the interesting lines, and count whether an error
# occurred, a "normal" occured or something else happened
error_counter = 0
normal_counter = 0
else_counter = 0
for line in interesting_lines:
    if 'Error' in line:
        error_counter+=1
    elif 'Normal' in line:
        normal_counter+=1
    else:
        else_counter+=1

# Here we print out the output. Of course you can use these counter variables
# somewhere else if you want
print(f"The last {seconds_interval} seconds had {error_counter} errors, {normal_counter} normals and {else_counter} elses in there")
```

The output for `seconds_interval = 4` and your data example is:

```
The last 4 seconds had 2 errors, 1 normals and 0 elses in there
```

Of course, this is a pretty crude approach. Everything depends on how variable your input is. For example, what if you have an `Error` and a `Normal` on the same line? I didn't add any error handling in there because the edge cases are not known.

Hope this helps you! :)